# Is it possible to trigger Intersection Observer callback every scroll/pixel?

Tags: javascript, svg, intersection-observer

I'm using Intersection Observer API instead of scroll events for my animations but I just ran into a problem when trying to animate SVG along the `offset-path` depending on scroll position and scroll value.

```
path.style.offsetDistance = element.intersectionRatio * 100 + "%";
```

Since Intersection Observer callback fires every time it passes through `threshold` values defined in `options` object, using `element.intersectionRatio` to animate `offset-distance` gives me glitchy aniamtion that fires only every 25% percentage of scroll. I could put every 1% in options object for threshold, like so:

```
let options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: "20px",
  threshold: [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, .....]
};
```

but is there a better solution or should I just switch to good old scroll events and use scrollY value in the formula to calculate offset-distance smoothly every scroll/pixel?

The rest of the code:

```
let options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: "20px",
  threshold: [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
};

let callback = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(element => {
        if (element.isIntersecting) {
            element.target.querySelectorAll("path").forEach(path => {
                path.setAttribute("style", "offset-path: path('M" + generateRandomAnimationPathM() +" " + generateRandomAnimationPathM() + " L " + generateRandomAnimationPathLine() + " " + generateRandomAnimationPathLine() + "')", "offset-rotate: 0deg");
                path.style.offsetDistance = element.intersectionRatio * 100 + "%";
            });
        }
    });   
}

let generateRandomAnimationPathM = () => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(100));
}

let generateRandomAnimationPathLine = () => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(200));
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

document.querySelectorAll('section').forEach(section => {
    console.log(section)
    observer.observe(section);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth noticing that **what you're proposing** with the threshold trick **is a hack and it's not guaranteed to work 100% of the time.**
This is because internally the IntersectionObserver API uses the window.requestIdleCallback which will request the browser to execute the callback only when it has time and the user isn't interacting with it. This means that even after setting the threshold every 0.01 step the animation could still result glitchy because some steps may get skipped.
What you're trying to achieve can easily be done, as you already said, by using the window.scrollY to calculate your elements' intersection ratio on scrollEvents.

Comment: Thanks. I already ended up using threshold hack but with time will probably abandon Observer and switch to scroll events. All over internet everyone is saying scroll events are outdated and you should use Observer API but no one talks about exceptions like this.

Comment: Surely the intersectionObserver Is a newer API that allows to do many things that before you could only di with the scrollEvent (lazy loading, timed animation, event triggers based on scroll position and so on...) but It's not a replacement for it and It was never meant to be ! Hope that It's a little clearer now 

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks!